# Trigger to fire on Event object only when 'assigned to' field is changed

Tags: trigger, event

I could really use some help on this one.  I have a requirement to send an email based an 'Event' being created (since, workflows don't allow this on the event & tasks object).  This is my code below for that.  Could someone please help show me how this would work now to ONLY fire when the Assigned To (Owner) is changed on the Event record?  Thanks!

```
Trigger Send_Email_Record_AssignedTo_Update on Event (after update) {

    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Event evt: Trigger.New)
        ownerIds.add(evt.ownerId);


    Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([select Name, Email from User where Id in :ownerIds]);
    for(Event evt : Trigger.New)
    {
        User theUser = userMap.get(evt.ownerId);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {theUser.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);    // Set the TO addresses
        mail.setSubject('A Scheduled Procedure has been assigned to you');    


        String template = 'Hello {0}, \nA Scheduled Procedure has been assigned to you. Here are the details - \n\n';
        template+= 'Subject: {1}\n';
        template+= 'Scheduled Start: {2}\n';
        template+= 'For all procedure details, please click the URL: {3}' + evt.Id ;
        String duedate = '';
        if (evt.StartDateTime==null)
            duedate = '';
        else
            duedate = evt.StartDateTime.format();
        List<String> args = new List<String>();
        args.add(theUser.Name);
        args.add(evt.Subject);
        args.add(duedate);
        args.add(evt.Event_URL__c);


        String formattedHtml = String.format(template, args);

        mail.setPlainTextBody(formattedHtml);
        Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Trigger Send_Email_Record_AssignedTo_Update on Event (after update) {

    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Event evt: Trigger.New)
    {
       if(evt.ownerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(evt.Id).ownerId)
       {
          ownerIds.add(evt.ownerId);
       }
    }
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstEmail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([select Name, Email from User where Id in :ownerIds]);
    for(Event evt : Trigger.New)
    {
         if(userMap.containskey(evt.ownerId)){
            User theUser = userMap.get(evt.ownerId);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {theUser.Email};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);    // Set the TO addresses
            mail.setSubject('A Scheduled Procedure has been assigned to you');    


            String template = 'Hello {0}, \nA Scheduled Procedure has been assigned to you. Here are the details - \n\n';
            template+= 'Subject: {1}\n';
            template+= 'Scheduled Start: {2}\n';
            template+= 'For all procedure details, please click the URL: {3}' + evt.Id ;
            String duedate = '';
            if (evt.StartDateTime==null)
                duedate = '';
            else
                duedate = evt.StartDateTime.format();
            List<String> args = new List<String>();
            args.add(theUser.Name);
            args.add(evt.Subject);
            args.add(duedate);
            args.add(evt.Event_URL__c);


            String formattedHtml = String.format(template, args);

            mail.setPlainTextBody(formattedHtml);
            lstEmail.add(mail);
        }

    }
    Messaging.SendEmail(lstEmail);
}
```

put a condition above `evt.ownerId ! = Trigger.oldMap.get(evt.Id).ownerId`

if new ownerId not equal to old ownerId  then store the id and proceed with rest functionality.

`Messaging.SendEmail(lstEmail)` always out side of for loop else you will hit salesforce governor limit.

In a single transaction 10 times Messaging.SendEmail can be called

Comment: Ratan, thanks for the heads up!  I'm now receiving this compile error based on you code.  Any clue on how to address it?  Also, would I need to change the trigger to .Old or keep it at .New?  Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found '!' at line 6 column 22  Which is: if(evt.ownerId ! = Trigger.oldMap.get(evt.Id).ownerId){

Comment: `if(evt.ownerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(evt.Id).ownerId){`  remove space b/w ! and =

Comment: thanks for that.  Now i'm getting this: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>].add() at line 41 column 13.  Which is: lstEmail.add();  Is it because of where it falls in the brackets?

Comment: It should be `lstEmail.add(mail);`

Comment: now a change has come up to place a checkbox on the user object, and this trigger needs to verify this logic (Opt_In_for_Procedure_Scheduler_Emails__c = true).  If true, then run the email trigger.  If false, Null.  Any assistance on how this would be implemented here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @JoshuaDavis Add `Opt_In_for_Procedure_Scheduler_Emails__c = true` condition in inside your trigger.new for loop. Check if this true then send email